# How to merge old commit in master branch with xCode 5

Tags: xcode, git, merge

Is it possible to merge an old commit I made into the master branch directly in xCode. I know I can merge my current branch into another branch but sometime I continue working on my project while the older commit is being test. When that commit is validated, I want to merge it into the master branch in xCode, is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible
steps for u can follow

- `git log` and find the specific commit
- `git fetch origin <commit_id>`
- `git checkout FETCH_HEAD`
- checkout to another new branch `git checkout -b <branch_name>`
- merge into master `git merge -s ours master`
- checkout to master `git checkout master`
- merger the branch what we created with master `git merge <branch_name>`
- commit
- push `git push --all`